# Getting exception kendo angular grid

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

`Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'filterable' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid'.`

1. `If 'kendo-grid' is an Angular component and it has 'filterable' input, then verify that it is part of this module.`
2. `If 'kendo-grid' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message.
   ("
   <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [ERROR ->][filterable]="true">`

Comment: Can you write the line of code from you `html` file where you try to bind to the `filterable` attribute?

Comment: <kendo-grid [data]="gridView"
                         [sortable]="true"
                         [sort]="sort"
                         [pageable]="true"
                         [pageSize]="5"
                         [filterable] ="true"
                         (sortChange)="sortChange($event)"
                >

Answer (score 0):

You're using an older version of the Kendo UI Grid for Angular 2. The `filterable` option was added not that long ago. From the [changelog](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/changelog/) it seems it was added in version 0.20.0 on March 24th, 2017.

What version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015/17 with "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.28.0",